How to call a function from an anonymous PLSQL block
I have 2 functions :
one in a package, one outside a package with a simple create function.
In my anonymous block, I try to call them :
declare
...

begin

   my_variable := get_myfunction_outside_a_package();

   my_other_variable := PK_myPackage.get_function_inside_a_package();

end;

This call would work inside a package.
Here, I have errors saying that those functions are not defined...
Is it possible to call those functions inside an anonymous block...How to do that ?

My code :
-- my package
create or replace PACKAGE my_Package
as
type my_type is table of number(10,2) index by varchar2(3);
...

-- my package body
create or replace PACKAGE BODY my_Package
as
...
function my_function_inside_the_package is
begin
...
end my_function_inside_the_package;


-- a function outside any package
create or replace function my_function_outside is
begin
...
end my_function_outside;

-- my anonymous block inside a sql file
declare
  my_associative_array my_package.my_type
begin
  my_associative_array := my_package.my_function_inside_the_package;
  my_variable := my_function_outside;
end;

executing the anonymous block :
PLS-00201 : identifier 'myPackage.my_type' must be declared

And for my_function_outside it is the same...

Please edit your question to include the full error message, and at least the function specifications - perhaps they are expecting arguments, or your local variables are the wrong types. Are the function and package in the same schema you're trying to call them from?

Maybe the anonymous block is connected as a different user/schema on the DB. For example if you have a DB user/schema "A" and "B", when the functions and packages are defined under "A" and you are calling those in a anonymous block connected to "B", you should call the function as select A. get_myfunction_outside_a_package() from dual;

Your code works (if you define the variables, function and package):
CREATE FUNCTION get_myfunction_outside_a_package RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN 42;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE PK_myPackage
IS
  FUNCTION get_function_inside_a_package RETURN NUMBER;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY PK_myPackage
IS
  FUNCTION get_function_inside_a_package RETURN NUMBER
  IS
  BEGIN
    RETURN 6 * 9;
  END;
END;
/

Then:
declare
  my_variable NUMBER;
  my_other_variable NUMBER;
begin
   my_variable := get_myfunction_outside_a_package();
   my_other_variable := PK_myPackage.get_function_inside_a_package();

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_variable);
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_other_variable);
end;
/

Outputs:
42
54

fiddle


my functions return associative arrays.

That works too.
Define the associative array in a package so it is available to be used:
CREATE PACKAGE pk_with_type
IS
  TYPE assoc_array IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(20) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(20);
END;
/

Then use it:
CREATE FUNCTION get_myfunction_outside_a_package
  RETURN pk_with_type.assoc_array
IS
  v_ary pk_with_type.assoc_array;
BEGIN
  v_ary('X') := '42';
  RETURN v_ary;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE PK_myPackage
IS
  FUNCTION get_function_inside_a_package RETURN pk_with_type.assoc_array;
END;
/

CREATE PACKAGE BODY PK_myPackage
IS
  FUNCTION get_function_inside_a_package RETURN pk_with_type.assoc_array
  IS
    v_ary pk_with_type.assoc_array;
  BEGIN
    v_ary('Y') := '6 * 9';
    RETURN v_ary;
  END;
END;
/

declare
  my_variable pk_with_type.assoc_array;
  my_other_variable pk_with_type.assoc_array;
begin
   my_variable := get_myfunction_outside_a_package();
   my_other_variable := PK_myPackage.get_function_inside_a_package();

   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_variable('X'));
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_other_variable('Y'));
end;
/

(Note: The associative array could be defined in the same package as the package function.)
fiddle

Updated for the edited question:
create or replace PACKAGE my_Package
as
  type my_type is table of number(10,2) index by varchar2(3);

  function my_function_inside_the_package RETURN my_package.my_type;
END;
/

create or replace PACKAGE BODY my_Package
as
  function my_function_inside_the_package RETURN my_package.my_type
  is
    v_ary my_package.my_type;
  begin
    v_ary('Q') := 6 * 9;
    v_ary('A') := 42;
    
    RETURN v_ary;
  end my_function_inside_the_package;
end;
/

declare
  my_associative_array my_package.my_type;
begin
  my_associative_array := my_package.my_function_inside_the_package;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_associative_array('Q'));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(my_associative_array('A'));
end;
/

Outputs:
54
42

fiddle

cannot do that because my functions return associative arrays.

@mlwacosmos Yes, you can. Change the data-type of the variable(s) in the DECLARE section to the associative array type (rather then NUMBER).

I am talking about the create function..;you cannot return an associative array. This type is forbidden..exactly the index by is forbidden...plus the function created with the create function or the one inside the package are invisible to my anonymous block..this is the point of my question.

@mlwacosmos Your question does not mention associative arrays and you CAN return an associative array from a function (it is not forbidden). fiddle

If you look closely at your error message it shows...
PLS-00201 : identifier 'myPackage.my_type' must be declared
when you compare this to your package definition it is clear you have a typo....
my_Package (declaration) vs myPackage (error message)
Not sure if this is your only issue but it is certainly one of them
